# URI_INTENT_SCHEME Specification

Tags: android, android-intent

The method:

```
Intent.parseUri(..., Intent.URI_INTENT_SCHEME)
```

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#parseUri%28java.lang.String,%20int%29

available since API level 4 allows to "serialize" essentially all of
an Intent instance data into a URI under the "intent:" scheme.

1) Is there an official, published specification for that URI scheme?

It doesn't seem to be listed on http://www.iana.org/assignments/uri-schemes.html

2) Are URIs generated with `Intent.toUri()` and consumed by
`Intent.parseUri()` stable/supported across API versions (supported in
future platform version)?

Comment: just "earned" the "tumbleweed" badge for that question;) don't know if that's a good thing .. come on .. no one there?

Comment: That would be great! I'd assume no, there is no official spec. Google is so silent, seems it must be intentional; they aren't ready to call this an "API." I think it's only safe to assume that toUri() and parseUri() are compatible in the *same* Android API Level. One could experiment with existing API Levels, write unit tests to use with future ones, and/or watch the [source](http://source.android.com/source/index.html).